# Issue with Search service account SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

ISSUE:

Using built-in accounts like Network Service or Local System as application pool or as service identities is not supported in a farm configuration.  The following services are currently running as built-in identities on one or more servers: OSearch15(Windows Service)

[image]

INFORMATION:

All the search service accounts are set to the domain/sharepointsearch account and all four servers are showing the same account being used for the running windows service.

What would cause this error to continue to pop up with the correct account being used everywhere?

Is there a script I can run that would double check or force SharePoint to recognize that the correct account is in fact being used?

Comment: account which is running the SharePoint Search service, is that registered in the Managed account in central admin > security > configure managed accounts?

Comment: yes it is registered as a managed account

Comment: did you check under which account app pool of search is running, try to go  Central Administration -> Manage Service Accounts >on this page select Search service and in the account drop down see which account is here...if local service then change it to your search account

Answer (score 1):

This service is not configured to use your domain\sharepointsearch account by default and will run as a local account instead.

You can use the following PowerShell to set this account to the user account you want to use:

```
$service_user = "domain\sharepointsearch"
$service_password = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyComplexPassword" -AsPlainText -force)
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -ServiceAccount $service_user -ServicePassword $service_password
```

Comment: This is the error I'm getting with that. The credentials are fine as I've added them to be a managed account and even logged in with them. 


Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService : The specified credentials are invalid.

Comment: Assuming you performed the lines above correctly, I would check the password, try opening up IE as that user in the server and see if it takes or gets denied.